# String declaration in java with _ named

Tags: java

I have peace of code who does the concatanation of string :-

```
String _‎ = "Hello ";
String _‏ = "World";
String _‎‏ = " !!";
System.out.println(_‎‏+_‎‏+_‎‏+_‎‏+_‎+_‏+_‎‏);
```

The output of code is :-

```
!! !! !! !!Hello World !!
```

I have few question :-

1. how can we declared the same named variable **(_)**
2. how the output is calculated

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: yes i have checked many times

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_91"

Comment: I have checked it with java 8, and surprisingly, the stated output is what I get, too! How come...

Comment: You're having some funny (but legal) characters, which make the variable names different

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra So you think your post is a gag, and we have to vote up if we find this funny ? ^^

Comment: Liked this question. :D, My IDE is being crazy with so many underscores now.

Answer (score 17):

This is just a stupid gimmicky trick:

The three underscores are all different characters/Strings, but look the same to the human eye.

If you print there values as a bytearray

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("_‎".getBytes()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("_‏".getBytes()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("_‎‏".getBytes()));
```

you will get the output:

```
[95, -30, -128, -114]
[95, -30, -128, -113]
[95, -30, -128, -114, -30, -128, -113]
```

The code you posted is therefore equivalent to the following:

```
String a = "Hello ";
String b = "World";
String c = " !!";
System.out.println(c+c+c+c+a+b+c);
```

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra - What more do you want? They're different characters, exactly as though `a`, `b`, and `c` were used as the variable names instead of `_‎`, `_`, and `_`.

Comment: It seems the underscore gets different character codes, what makes the compiler assume different variable names, right @T.J.Crowder?

Comment: ohk but when i type _+_ which one it will take (i mean can it be different from JVM to JVM)

Comment: If you use eclipse, try refactoring the first declaration, it won't take all of the `_`-characters (as I just found out).

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra If you use `_‎`, you will get the first one; if you use `_‏` you will get the second one; if you use `_‎‏`, you will get the third one.

Comment: I understood but how it is calculating the output for *System.out.println(_‎‏+_‎‏+_‎‏+_‎‏+_‎+_‏+_‎‏);* As per the calculation for *print* statement left to right is calculated (same precedence)

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra i don't really understand your last question. I think you still have problems understanding that the code you posted has 3 different variables with 3 different names. They are completely different but they just look the same to your human eye, but to your computer those 3 underscores are completly different symbols. I added the code how it would look if you would choose a,b and c as variable names. In the original code someone just thought he could play a trick on people by choosing 3 different symbols that look the same as variable names.

Comment: why it is *(c+c+c+c+a+b+c);* ? this is the question

Comment: I'm sorry, but i really don't know how to explain this any better or how else. You have 3 DIFFERENT Variables. You don't have 3 variables with the same name, they are different but are printed on your monitor to look the same to your human eye. But the representation inside your computer as bytes is completly different as i showed in the answer above and that is all that matters for your omputer and thats why he doesn't care that those 3 different symbols look like they are the same to you. So why is it (c+c+c+c+a+b+c)? Because whoever wrote the code wrote it that way.

Comment: The following Strings are all different: `_`,`_‏`, `_‎‏` - The following is one ‏String repeated 3 times: `_`, `_`, `_`  // Can you spot the difference? No, but your computer can tell the difference because he doesn't use his eyes to distuingish between Strings but looks at their representation in bits and bytes in his memory.

Comment: actually the 3 variable are beginning by the normal _ character but the second is followed by unicode character `\u200e` (left-to-right mark) which is not printable and the third followed by this character twice

Comment: or rather, `\u200e` (left-to-right mark) and `\u200f` (right-to-left mark) are valid identifier parts characters in java are not printed : first variable is equivalent to `"_\u200e"`, second `"_\u200f"` and third `"_\u200e\u200f"`. Note that `\u200d` (0-width-joiner) should also be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Java 9 underscore is strictly not allowed (See [Java 9 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/language/toc.htm#JSLAN-GUID-16A5183A-DC0D-4A96-B9D8-AAC9671222DD))

> #### The underscore character is not a legal name.
>
> If you use the underscore character ("_") an identifier, your source
> code can no longer be compiled.

I tried to run this and got error.

> (use of '_' as an identifier might not be supported in releases after
> Java SE 8)

#### So good for you not to use underscore from now.

Obviously, If they said not to use underscore, then there is some reason behind this.